# [AbstractProvider.GetProvider]: The object type '....' is missing the provider type configuration

Tags: kentico

I keep getting this error on our dev and qa environments in a Kentico 9.0 mvc application that I created.  I did find this site that recommends that you clear out the temporary asp.net folders to fix the issue, (http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/error-cms-document-is-missing-the-provider-type-configuration) and this fixes the issue for a short period of time but after an hour or so the error comes back. I'm not having this issue on my local box at all and I've triple checked all the area's where I have the class name in strings.

We are running a weird configuration though, we've got one site setup and 2 applications setup under that one site. One for kentico and one for our mvc app which interacts with kentico. Both have their own application pool and are using Integrated Pipeline Mode.

Any ideas??

Comment: Did you include [CMSDependencies](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-kentico-api-externally#UsingtheKenticoAPIexternally-IntegratingKenticoAPIlibraries) in all your external projects and all your environments?

Comment: + Are you using the official [NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.Libraries/)?

Comment: I'm using the nuget packages and I have the CMSDependencies folder, but they weren't being copied over during the build.  I've made sure they are being copied over and I just did a push to our QA server.  We'll see if that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  We haven't had it occur since yesterday evening when I made that change.  @MartinMakarsky if you want put your comment in as an answer and I'll mark it has being the correct answer.   And thanks both of you.

Comment: I`ve added it as an answer for another people dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should include CMSDependencies in all your external projects and all your environments. - [source](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-kentico-api-externally#UsingtheKenticoAPIexternally-IntegratingKenticoAPIlibraries)